# Show that a set is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Show that the set of functions S= {$\frac{sin(nx)}{n}$}$_{n≥1}$ on $I=[0,1]$ is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded.

I'm not really sure how to go about this, could anyone offer any help?

Comment: Do you mean bounded in $(C^0([0,1]),||\cdot||_\infty)$?

Comment: Uniform boundedness is clear since $|\sin(t)|\le1$. For equicontinuity, note that the Mean Value Theorem shows that if $f_n'$ is uniformly bounded on an interval then $(f_n)$ is equicontinuous.